# How can I get background color of RichEdit by mouseClick?

Tags: delphi

There are a lot of references on how to set a background color in a RichEdit, eg:

```
procedure TBReaderF.SetBGColor(RichEdit: TRichEdit; AColor: TColor);
var
  Format: CHARFORMAT2;
begin
  FillChar(Format, SizeOf(Format), 0);
  with Format do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(Format);
    dwMask := CFM_BACKCOLOR;
    crBackColor := AColor;
    Richedit.Perform(EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, Longint(@Format));
  end;
end;
```

But, I can't find any way on how to retrieve the color.

Comment: If you use [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcharformat) to set the format, maybe you can use [`EM_GETCHARFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getcharformat) to get it?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The returned color for  EM_GETCHARFORMAT is always black 0

Comment: FillChar(Format, SizeOf(Format), 0);
   with Format do
   begin
     cl := Richedit.Perform(EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, Longint(@Format));
   end;

Comment: Sorry for my awful formatting, I hope I will learn how to do it properly soon

Comment: That snippet will not work; you must set the `cbSize` member (at least). From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-charformata): "Size in bytes of the specified structure. This member must be set before passing the structure to the rich edit control."

Comment: Well, Andreas, be so kind, show me this snippet, if it's short.

Comment: I am not very strong in API

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcharformat) to *set* the format, one might guess that you use [`EM_GETCHARFORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getcharformat) to *get* it.

For example¹,

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnSetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var F := Default(CHARFORMAT2);
  F.cbSize := SizeOf(F);
  F.dwMask := CFM_BACKCOLOR;
  F.crBackColor := clSkyBlue;
  RichEdit1.Perform(EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, NativeInt(@F));

end;

procedure TForm1.btnGetClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var F := Default(CHARFORMAT2);
  F.cbSize := SizeOf(F);
  RichEdit1.Perform(EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, NativeInt(@F));

  ShowMessage(ColorToString(F.crBackColor));

end;
```

Please note that all you need to know about this topic is well covered in its documentation.

Indeed, every time you use a new API, you need to read its complete documentation. That's not a "nice to do" thing, but a "must do" thing.

In this case, read the documentation for the `EM_GETCHARFORMAT` message, as well as the documentation for the [`CHARFORMAT2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-charformat2w) structure you use.

According to the structure's documentation:

> cbSize: Size in bytes of the specified structure. This member must be set before passing the structure to the rich edit control.

---

¹ Here I assume you are using a recent Delphi version. If you are not, you need to declare `var F: CHARFORMAT2` in the `var` section before `begin` since inline variable declarations have not been invented yet in your version. Also, instead of `F := Default(CHARFORMAT2)`, you need to do a boring `FillChar(F, SizeOf(F), 0)`.

Comment: Andreas, thank you very much! It's all work just as it needed. And yes, I know where to declare variables in new version in Delphi (as well as old ones). I wish I knew it as well in using API. But your advice (That's not a "nice to do" thing, but a "must do" thing.) well noted. Thanks again!